# Angular: Evaluate Expression Passed into Component Attribute

Tags: angularjs, components

How can I pass in the value of an Angular expression to a component's attribute? I'm getting the value back from an API.

**app.controller.js**

```
$http.get(apiUrl).then(function(resp) {
  $scope.name = resp.data.name;
})
...
```

**person.component.js**

```
export const Person = {
  templateUrl: 'person.html',
  bindings: {
      firstName: '@'
  },
  controller: function() {
      console.log(this.firstName);
  }
}
```

**app.html**

```
...
<person first-name="name">
```

For some reason it's not evaluating `name` and it's logging `undefined` in the console.

Is there a way around this so it logs `Tom` inside the controller?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

I've setup a jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/d2m32gp4/5/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&` is for expressions, and `@` is for interpolated strings, so try using

```
firstName: '&'
```

and then `this.firstName()` should evaluate the expression passed in.

Also, `firstName` is not guaranteed to have been initialized until `$onInit`, so if you do

```
bindings: {
    firstName: '&'
},
controller: function() {
    this.$onInit = function() {
        console.log(this.firstName());
    }
}
```

you should get your expected result.

For reference: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component

> `$onInit()` - Called on each controller after all the controllers on an element have been constructed **and had their bindings initialized**

## Edit:

After the extra information you provided, you should probably use a one-way binding (`<`) instead for this case, because it appears you are just passing in a single value (instead of an expression), and then you can detect changes in `$onChanges`. I forked your jsfiddle to show a potential solution: http://jsfiddle.net/35xzeo94/.

Comment: I should have explained that I'm getting the data back from an API, so it's not readily available on load. I've set up a jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/d2m32gp4/5/)

Comment: @realph If it's just a variable and not an expression, then you can use a one-way `<` binding. In this case `$onChanges` will get called when the value is updated.  But if it's truly an expression, then you won't be able to see the updated value, unless it's in the view for component.  This is because components aren't meant to have inputs this way, they are supposed to be `@` or `<`, and outputs are supposed to be what `&` is for. Also, in your jsfiddle, you have `name="customerId"` instead of `name="name"`.

Comment: @realph I forked your jsfiddle in my answer to show one way to do it.